# Creating a Matlab run line shortcut (like R)

Tags: macos, matlab

R has a great shortcut that runs the line your cursor is currently on then moves the cursor onto the next line (`cmd + return`). In matlab, you have to highlight the line then run the highlighted section (`shift + F7`).

Is there a way to create an 'R like' run line shortcut? I'm using OSX.

Comment: Usually what I do is to separate the specific parts with %% lines and the CTRL+ENTER to run just that piece of specific code.

Comment: That's a good workaround but it would be pretty messy to litter my code with it just because I want to test one line. I'm really just interested to see if anyone has been able to make a shortcut to do this.

Comment: In debug mode, you can step through your code like that. To run just a single line, double click the line (should highlight whole line) and then F9 to run it.

Comment: you can try to define a new shortcut on your own. Follow this: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/keyboard-shortcuts.html

Comment: @kungfujam if you manage to do this, please post it as a solution

Comment: Will do, I think that the starter from @lakesh may only work if Matlab has the command built in...but I could be wrong. I'll investigate later.

Comment: @kungfukam i don't think that you need to have a command built in. You can create one. Read on this: http://matlab.izmiran.ru/help/techdoc/matlab_env/deskto19.html#102820

Comment: Just to update, I have tried to follow this. I tried the hack of assigning two commands (select line and run selection) to one shortcut. Unfortunately, on my mac it just executes one of the commands.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. On the Home tab, click New, and then select Command Shortcut.
2. In the Label field: enter a name for the shortcut.
   In the Callback field:

   currentEditor = matlab.desktop.editor.getActive;
   originalSelection = currentEditor.Selection; assert(originalSelection(1)==originalSelection(3));
   currentEditor.Selection = [originalSelection(1) 1 originalSelection(1) Inf]; disp(currentEditor.SelectedText);
   eval(currentEditor.SelectedText);
   currentEditor.Selection = originalSelection + [1 0 1 0];

Now I can run the line I'm on by pressing Alt+s+1 (perhaps you can change this to an arbitrary hotkey). I hope this helps.

EDIT: In MATLAB R2018a Command Shortcuts [have been repackaged as Favorite Commands](https://it.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/389819-where-have-the-command-shortcuts-gone-in-r2018a). So to create a new shortcut in this and later version, you need to go Home tab -> Favorites -> New Favorite.

EDIT: You currently (in MATLAB R2020b) can run this code with Alt+1 (no need for 's' as above). However, it does not appear to be changeable in Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts

Comment: This works! Where is the reference for these commands? I'd like to make it such that the cursor moves to the next line after running.

Comment: Good to hear! Try finding your way from this link: http://blogs.mathworks.com/community/2009/10/26/the-matlab-editor-at-your-fingertips/

Comment: have just updated your code such that it performs as it does in R

Comment: For whatever reason my edit does not look like it will be approved...
to make it act like R as my original question asks simply add
`disp(currentEditor.SelectedText);` and
`currentEditor.Selection = originalSelection + [1 0 1 0];`

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks for commenting your edit though, @kungfujam!

Comment: Feel free to add it to your answer as an edit - it better answers my question!

Comment: Right you are ;) Done!

Comment: ...sorry, there's now no need for the 3rd from last line
`currentEditor.Selection = originalSelection;`

Comment: Nothing changed for me :s It still runs one line and stays there. It doesn't go to the next line.

Comment: currentEditor = matlab.desktop.editor.getActive; originalSelection = currentEditor.Selection; assert(originalSelection(1)==originalSelection(3)); currentEditor.Selection = [originalSelection(1) 1 originalSelection(1) Inf]; disp(currentEditor.SelectedText); eval(currentEditor.SelectedText); currentEditor.Selection = originalSelection + [1 0 1 0]; works for me on matlab 2015.

Answer (score 0):

```
currentEditor = matlab.desktop.editor.getActive; 
originalSelection = currentEditor.Selection; 
currentEditor.Selection = [originalSelection(1) 1 originalSelection(3) Inf]; disp(currentEditor.SelectedText); 
eval(currentEditor.SelectedText); 
currentEditor.Selection = [originalSelection(3),0,originalSelection(3),0]+[1,0,0,0];
```