# Is there a shortcut to execute the current line in Matlab code?

Tags: matlab, debugging, keyboard-shortcuts

When you select a line / multiple lines of code in Matlab, you can press `F9` to execute it / them.

Is there a shortcut to execute the current line of code? This would enable you to go down line per line with your `arrow down` key and execute the corresponding line with this `shortcut`.

Comment: This might help http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/132119-keyboard-shortcut-to-evaluate-current-line

Comment: The solution by Joseph Cheng doesn't work in newer versions of MATLAB (2015/2016). Any idea how to get it to work?

Comment: Binding "Selection End Line" to F8 and then click F8->F9 will do the job very quickly, if the cursor is at the beginning of the line. Two buttons instead of one, and cursor needs to be placed correctly though.

Comment: shift+end or shift+home is not enough?

Answer (score 6):

While this is an older question, I don't find the only answer particularly satisfying.

This works in MatLab R2020b and R2021a at least (not sure about others).

On the home tab select *Favorites*, then *New Favorite*, then a cleaned version of the following code from this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/36149189/9096420) can be entered into the *Code:* section

```
currentEditor = matlab.desktop.editor.getActive; 
originalSelection = currentEditor.Selection; assert(originalSelection(1)==originalSelection(3)); 
currentEditor.Selection = [originalSelection(1) 1 originalSelection(1) Inf]; disp(currentEditor.SelectedText); 
eval(currentEditor.SelectedText); 
currentEditor.Selection = originalSelection + [1 0 1 0];
```

After that select *Add to quick access toolbar* and you can run one line at a time with `Alt`+`1` (It is actually `Alt` and then `1` very shortly after, as opposed to simultaneously)

Note: The last line of this code will drop the cursor one line in the Editor. If you want it to stay on that line, just remove this last part.

---

The one place where this does fail is when you run `clear all`, because this line is evaluated *before* (second to last line above) you go a line down (last line above). So the `clear all` will still work, but the cursor will not drop and you will get an error: `Unrecognized function or variable 'originalSelection'.`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to manually select the line and run it, you could put a break point in the script at the line you want to start from and run with debug. By running the debugger you can then step through the lines you want to run. If the code is inside a function it won't keep the workspace variables when you terminate the debugger, but if it is a script file, you will still have access to them.